# convert local date time to UTC time in php

Tags: php, datetime, utc

I'm trying to converting local date time to UTC time but it's not converting.
i'm using this:-

```
$check= 13-07-2015 12:03:41;
$userdate=gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($check));
```

Its giving me only 2 hours difference between my local time to UTC time but actual difference is 5:30 hours.
Please suggest me how to convert this.

Comment: And what is within `$check` can you post it that too

Comment: Please open up the command prompt and write `date +%z # GMT offset`. What is the result?

Comment: what are you getting Uchiha for this date and time??

Comment: [Check this](https://eval.in/397425) I'm getting `2015-07-13 06:33:41`

Comment: its giving me2015-07-13 10:03:26 date and time,but it should be           2015-07-13 06:32:45

Comment: hey thanku so much Uchiha..i was missing this   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

Comment: You're welcome... @Neha Do I need to post it as an answer

Comment: if you want to post,you can but for me its solved..i was stuck because of this only ..thanku so much again..:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$check` needs to be a string (I'll assume it is and you just forgot to add the quotes in the edit)

```
$check = '13-07-2015 12:03:41';
```

find out what timezone your php thinks you're in:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

if it's not your timezone (it should be something like 'Asia/Kolkata' from the 5 1/2 hrs difference) then update your `timezone` in your  `php.ini` file with the correct one

if you can't access your `php.ini` file then you'll need to set the timezone in your script using [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Hi Neha, did that sort your problem? if it did please then select as "best answer" thanks